# setting a cookie after include("file")

Tags: php

I have a login script and I log users that fail excessively.  In my debugging purposes I have it logging after the first try fail or not.

I tested the code by visiting it. I named the file fail_cookie.php.  When I visit it from the browser it sets the cookie just fine. However if I am on a login form called login.ws and I have this code:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE["login"])) {
        logUser($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], time(), $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        include "fail.ws";
    }
```

Inside `fail.ws` is where I set the `fail_cookie.php`.  I include this inside the `<head> .. .. <?php include("fail_cookie.php"); ?> </head>`

The cookie is never set when I am redirected to `fail.ws` by `login.ws`.

This code used to work on my last host but it doesn't work on my current host. Is it my host that is the problem or is it mine? If it is mine can someone point some advice to me?

Thanks.

Comment: Only for my mind... why **fail.ws**? And [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/de/function.setcookie.php) is nor working? Can you show the line where you set the cookie?

Comment: possible duplicate of [setting a cookie after header("Location...")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273363/setting-a-cookie-after-headerlocation)

Comment: I wonder how I duplicated, I'll delete the other.

Comment: What do *fail.ws* and *fail_cookie.php* do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable `output_buffering` in `php.ini`. Ths way you can set cookies after your php file sends output to the user. - In fact output will be buffered, and sent after your php script ends.

You can enable this also in a *.htccess* file with:

```
php_flag output_buffering on
```

Comment: Really? Wow I thought it was my problem haha I was ripping my hair out wondering what I did wrong.  Thanks a lot I'll have them enable that.

Comment: Well it is your problem. You are outputting stuff before sending headers (cookies are headers). Output buffering just writes everything to PHP's memory before sending it to the server - so it increases your memory usage.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, how can I fix this or do it the right way? Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Kyle You can reorganize your code. But if it worked fine with your last host it should work fine now. If you are ceating a high-traffic site then of course this is not advisable, but there are good books on the things you have to watch in that situation.

Comment: Do not mix PHP and HTML code but use templates which will be rendered at the end - after all headers have been sent.