# Setting cookie after headers sent. Why is it working ? It shouldn't

Tags: php, http, cookies

This code shouldn't work, because the cookie data should sent with the headres, before any other output.

```
<html>
<body>
text before setcookie
<?php

setcookie( "meaningoflife", "42", time()+42000 );
?>
</body>
</html>
```

But why I get the php from a browser, it will be set. Why ?
My PHP version is 5.3.6, apache 2.2.20 on a Mac OS X machine.

Comment: You probably have output buffering enabled. Check with [`ini_get("output_buffering")`](http://php.net/ini_get).

Comment: possible duplicate of [setting a cookie after include("file")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273375/setting-a-cookie-after-includefile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as @mario said:

> You probably have output buffering enabled. Check with
>   ini_get("output_buffering").